# How to print name of a user in Excel when in DB is set with its ID. PHP, Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I export a table from webpage based on Laravel framework to excel, but when I download the file it downloads.

But I want to show the user name which corresponds to a specific id in those files. Same for project. (but if find a solution for the user name, can use same solution for project too).

Comment: you want in excel sheet only name and id??

Comment: @KuldeepMishra I want all colums as shown in the pic, but where name_id is, I want to put the full name of the user. example: $user->fullName

Comment: You need to join whatever table houses the full name in your eloquent query based on that name_id.

Comment: for testing, I registered only 1 ID, but there will be different users.

Comment: @RobFonseca any idea how to do it?

Comment: If you post the structure of the table that has the full name and the associated model, yes

Comment: create a another array and pass it to excel like this ..
$data = Timesheet::get()->toArray(); this is your main array.
now
foreach$data as $datas){
  $data['full_name'] =  $datas->first_name.' '. $datas->last_name;
}
now your data has a new field like full_name

Comment: @RobFonseca done, take a look

Comment: you can also join based on that name_id from the table where is your full name availbble

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a join to you users table based on **user_id** in the Timesheets table. Modify your eloquent query to this:

```
$data = Timesheet::select('timesheets.name', 'timesheets.description',
                          'timesheets.project_id', 'users.fullName',
                          'timesheets.hours', 'timesheets.date',
                          'timesheets.created_at', 'timesheets.updated_at')
                 ->join('users', 'timesheets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->get()->toArray();
```

I am also specifying specific columns to pull so you can have full control what data appears in the spreadsheet.

I see you also have **project_id**, so you will want to add another join() method to your query for the projects table to handle that.

Comment: hey, sorry for getting late on you, I keep getting this error

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.fullName' in 'field list' (SQL: select `timesheets`.`name`, `timesheets`.`description`, `timesheets`.`project_id`, `users`.`fullName`, `timesheets`.`hours`, `timesheets`.`date`, `timesheets`.`created_at`, `timesheets`.`updated_at` from `timesheets` inner join `users` on `timesheets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`)so basically it doesnt find clients.fullName.

Comment: Is there a clients table? My answer has users.fullName. If ‘fullName’ doesn’t exist, you need to join the first and last name columns together

Comment: sorry, looks like it was a mistake of mine, I updated the comment. 
I meant users.fullName not clients

Comment: Is the column fullName in your users table? You haven’t shown the User model so we are flying blind as to what columns are in the table.

Comment: not exactly full name, I changed the code in here to first_name. but when the error come, I changed it from first_name to fullName not to confuse you with more stuff

Comment: You can’t pass a variable as a column name. Just replace users.fullName with users.first_name in my original answer. You should definitely which some videos on Laracasts on eloquent to get some of the basics down.